# alternating multiple row color every N rows and repeating

Tags: css

im trying to have a table where the first 5 rows would be blue, the next 5 would be red, then the next 5 would be blue again, and repeating

i have tried

```
    tr:nth-child(4n+0) {background:red;}
    tr:nth-child(4n+1) {background:blue;}
    tr:nth-child(4n+2) {background:yellow;}
```

but all i got was blue

i have also tried

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: yellow;
    /* possibly other styles */
}
```

but none worked.

a lot of the tutorial about this subject i see online is showing how to change every 4th row to be different color but what i want is change every 4 rows to be different

Answer (score 1):

Write `An+B` where `A` is the number of rows before the pattern repeats (12 in your case) and `B` is the index of the row within the pattern, starting with 1.

```css
tr { font-size: 6px; }

tr:nth-child(12n+1),
tr:nth-child(12n+2),
tr:nth-child(12n+3),
tr:nth-child(12n+4){ background: blue; }

tr:nth-child(12n+5),
tr:nth-child(12n+6),
tr:nth-child(12n+7),
tr:nth-child(12n+8){ background: red; }

tr:nth-child(12n+9),
tr:nth-child(12n+10),
tr:nth-child(12n+11),
tr:nth-child(12n+12){ background: yellow; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td></tr>

</table>
```